# Unable to locate @sheet/core package in npm repository

Tags: node.js, excel, express, xlsx, npm-package

There is a '@sheet/core' package dependency in my package.json file, which npm is unable to find in the repository.
When I try to install the dependency npm throws 404 not found error.
I've attached the packagejson file screenshot and error screenshot.
Please help me find a solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI4Of.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V5dg.png)

I run the following commands

- npm i

Error-
Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@sheet%2fcore - Not found

Answer (score 0):

I found that as well in my project. I did some searching and this library looks like successor or it is based on it.

https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

Most of the code is same so it should not be huge migration. Apparently they moved away from npmjs.com so read docs how to install.